# Finding nearest number in array

Tags: java

A have array with numbers, for example `1,2,3,4,5`.

I need to return the element which have nearest value to the average of whole array. 
For example,

```
1+2+3+4+5=15
15/5=3
```

The result should be the number 3.

If there is no number that is the same as the average, the result should be the nearest number from the array.

I need only the method which will return that value.

```
Integer sum = 0; 
Integer a = 0;
for(int i=0; i<array.getLength();i++)
{
   a = array.get(i); sum=sum+a; 
}
 Integer average= sum/array.getLength();
 return average;
}
```

I tried this, but it returns only the exact value as the average, not the nearest.

Comment: Should it return 2 numbers if the average is 3, and the array numbers are 2 and 4?

Comment: no, it should return the smaller number, in this case 2.

Comment: Integer sum = 0;
         Integer a = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<array.getLength();i++){
          a = array.get(i);
             sum=sum+a;
   }
        Integer average= sum/array.getLength();
        return average;
            }I tried this, but it returns only the exact value as the average, not the nearest.

Comment: I haven't round that because there are some restrictions where I can't use sorting methods

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution. Probably there could be used some more clever algorithm to get most close value from array if it is sorted.
If there are two numbers that are both nearest to average thi one wich occurst first in array is chosen.

**Edit** changed the comparation so the lowest number nearest to average is foud.

```java
public static Integer nearestToAverage(int[] res) {
    if (res.length < 1) {
        return null; //if there is no array return null;
    }
    int sum = 0; //variable to sum up the array
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        int act = res[i];
        sum += act; //adding elements of array to sum
    }
    int avg = sum / res.length; //computing the average value
    int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //set distance to integer max so it is higher than any of values in array
    Integer ret = null; //setting return value to null it will be replaced with value from array
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        int act = res[i];
        int actDistance = Math.abs(act - avg); //computing distance of actual value and average
        if ((actDistance < minDistance) || ((actDistance == minDistance) && (act < ret))) { //if it is less than actual minimal distance or it is the same and act number is lower than return value
            minDistance = actDistance; //the distance is set to new
            ret = act; //also is return value
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: oh there was some edits in meantime. If you want smallest of the closest numbers you could add if in place where actDistance and minDistance is compared for case it is equal and chose smaller value of ret and act

Answer (score 1):

```
void findelement()
    {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int a`enter code here`ve = 3, elem=0;
        long tempi=0, tempdiff;
        long diff=-1;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            tempdiff = (long)arr[i]-(long)ave;
            tempdiff = (tempdiff < 0 ? -tempdiff : tempdiff);
            diff = (diff==-1)?tempdiff : diff;
            if(diff>tempdiff){
                diff = tempdiff;
                elem = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("hi element is "+elem+" and value near to average is "+arr[elem]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
double closeDiff = 0;
double arravg = getAverage(arr); // write a method which will return the average
int resultIndex = 0;

for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
{

  if(arr[i-1] > arr[i])
  tempDiff = (arr[i-1] - arr[i]);
  else
    tempDiff = (-arr[i-1] + arr[i]);
  if(tempDiff<closeDiff)
   resultIndex = i;
}
return arr[i];
```

Comment: i'm sorry but:
1) i'm not following your logic, why trying to find values closest to avarage, you comparing two values from array with each other?
2) you have scope error, i what you use in you return statement is out of scope as it is defined only inside for statement